# Howto improve OCR results

Tags: open-source, ocr, tesseract

I tried to improved the results of OpenSource OCR software. I'm using tessaract, because I find it still produces better results than gocr, but with bad quality input it has huge problems. So I tried to prepocess the image with various tools I found in the internet:

- unpaper
- Fred's ImageMagick Scripts: TEXTCLEANER
- manuall using GIMP

But I was not able to get good results with this bad test document: (really just for test, I don't need to content of this file)
http://9gag.com/gag/aBrG8w2/employee-handbook

This online service works surprisingly good with this test document:
http://www.onlineocr.net/

I'm wonderung if it is possible using smart preprocessing to get similar results with tesseract. Are the OpenSource OCR engines really so bad compared to commercial ones? Even google uses tesseract to scan documents, so I was expecting more...

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract's precision in recognition is a little bit lower than the precision of the best commercial one (Abbyy FineReader), but it's more flexible because of its nature. 
This flexibility entail sometimes some preprocessing, because it's not possible for Tesseract to manage each situation.
Actually is used by google because is Google its main sponsor!

The first thing you could do is to try to expand the text in order to have at least 20 pixel wide characters or more. Since Tesseract works using as features the main segments of the characters' borders, it needs to have a bigger characters' size comparing with other algorithms.

Another thing that you could try, always referring to the test document you mentioned, is to binarize your image with an adaptive thresholding method (here you can find some infos about that https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2504), because some changes in the illumination are present. Tesseract binarizes the image internally, but this could be the case when it fails to do that (it's similar to the example here [Improving the quality of the output with Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality), where you can also find some other useful informations)

Comment: Increasing the resolution improved the results.
I played with adaptive threshold which solves the uneven ilumination, but has problems with white areas. I found 2colorthresh from Fred's ImageMagick Scripts to provide better results.
My current command looks like this:

    convert aBrG8w2_700b.jpg -resize 1600 -contrast -contrast -contrast +dither -colors 2 -colorspace gray -contrast-stretch 10% test.png && tesseract test.png test && cat test.txt

Much better, but still not really useable. Does anybody out there has a better approach?

Comment: The problem in with areas is because when playing with adaptive thresholding generally means to divide the image in small blocks, and than binarize each one by itself. So, in some blocks (like the white areas you were talking about) will be not present both a foreground (text) and background, and in this situations the binarization fails. 
I don't know how flexible the algorithm you are using is, but a solution could be subtract a constant from the threshold of each block, such that even if no text is present, the threshold value will be lower than the white background.

Comment: Anyway, even if the the thresholding algorithm you are using is not flexible, should not be a big problem to remove those artifact. An approach could be looking at the geometric properties of each blob.

Comment: I would be interested to learn concrete points why would Tesseract be better than any commercial OCR

Comment: I don't have the truth, it was just a simple thought derived by the fact that it's in continuing evolution and there is google behind it, that I think a good amount of data at disposal :) 
Anyway a concrete point for sure is the cost. About the performances (I'm reading now some comparisons) Abbyy FineReader seems generally more precise while Tesseract seems more flexible (e.g. in this test recognize image captions, while Abbyy was not able to do it http://www.labnol.org/software/google-ocr-software-review/7208/).
Maybe "better" was not the correct word, do you agree if I edit my answer?